# Matching different columns sport and dport from mysql table

Tags: mysql, security, packets

I have a table with UDP packets that is being stored for analysis.  I want to search for packets that were not solicited by my server.
For example if I receive an UDP packet from source port 106 and dst port 32767 and I never sent a packet out from my IP address

Here is the table structure.

```
mysql>show columns from packets;
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| stime  | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| sip    | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| dip    | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| sport  | smallint(6)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| dport  | smallint(6)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| in_out | tinyint(4)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| id     | smallint(6)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from packets limit 5;
+---------------------+------------+------------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| stime               | sip        | dip        | sport | dport | in_out | id    |
+---------------------+------------+------------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| 2012-12-03 20:59:45 |  167837953 | 3406507329 |  1029 |    53 |      0 | 32767 | 
| 2012-12-03 20:59:45 | 3406507329 |  167837953 |    53 |  1029 |      1 | 32767 | 
| 2012-12-03 20:59:46 | 3406507329 |  167837953 |    53 |  1029 |      1 | 32767 | 
| 2012-12-03 20:59:46 | 2399874369 |  167837953 |    53 | 32321 |      1 |  3000 | 
| 2012-12-03 21:00:02 | 2064330049 |  167837953 |    53 |  3349 |      1 |  1207 | 
+---------------------+------------+------------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In the example above the last two packets are unsolicited packets that I should be able to find with a query.  Basically if I get a packet that does not match tuple of `(source,dest,sourceport,dstport,id)` - I need to list all those rows in Mysql table.

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
SELECT *
FROM packets
LEFT JOIN packets_2 ON (
    packets.sip = packets_2.dip
    AND packets.dip = packets_2.sip
    AND packets.sport = packets_2.dport
    AND packets.dport = packets_2.sport
    AND packets.id = packets_2.id
    AND packets.stime <= packets_2.stime -- I think this makes sense
)
WHERE packets_2.id IS NULL
```